# How does the insert method work in a linked list?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a linked list using three classes `B`, `IntSet`, and `Node`.

Below is the code from my solution book. I need to know two things:

1. In class `B` I do not know what to write in the `main` method to run my code.
2. I need someone to describe me the `insert` method in the class `B`. I do understand the first `if` statement in the `insert` method, but I do not understand the other `if` statements in the `insert method`.

Here are the three classes:

```
package person;

public class B implements IntSet {
    private Node first;
    private int size;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public B() {
        first = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        first.next = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int nbr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node p = first;
        while (p != null) {
            if (p.min <= nbr && p.max >= nbr) {
                return true;
            }
            if (p.min > nbr) {
                return false;
            }
            p = p.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(int nbr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node p = first;
        while (p != null) {
            if (p.min <= nbr && p.max >= nbr) {
                return false;
            }
            if (p.max + 1 == nbr && p.next.min - 1 == nbr) {
                p.max = p.next.max;
                p.next = p.next.next;
                break;
            } else if (p.max + 1 == nbr) {
                p.max = nbr;
                break;
            } else if (p.next.min - 1 == nbr) {
                p.next.min = nbr;
                break;
            } else if (p.max < nbr && p.next.min > nbr) {
                Node n = new Node(nbr, nbr);
                n.next = p.next;
                p.next = n;
                break;
            }
            p = p.next;
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }
}

package person;

public interface IntSet {
    /** Tar reda på om nbr finns i mängden. */
    boolean contains(int nbr);

    /**
     * Sätter in nbr i mängden om det inte redan finns. Returnerar true om nbr
     * kan sättas in i mängden, i annat fall false.
     */
    boolean insert(int nbr);

    /* Tar reda på antal tal i mängden. */
    public int size();
}

package person;

class Node {
    int min;
    int max;
    Node next;

    Node(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @honk can you describe me the insert method in the class B ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Java well enough. I just edited your question, because I was reviewing a suggested edit on your question. But I think you already got some helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First implement `toString` method in your `B` class. Below is the code for `toString` and `main` method.

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         Node p = first;
         while (p != null) { 
             builder.append("[").append(p.min).append(",").append(p.max).append("]");
             p = p.next;
         }
         return builder.toString();
    }
```

And `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();

    System.out.println("Before any insert :" +b);

    b.insert(1);
    b.insert(4);

    System.out.println("After first insert :" +b);

    b.insert(18);
    b.insert(23);

    System.out.println("After second insert :" +b);

    b.insert(25);
    b.insert(25);

    System.out.println("After third insert :" +b);

    b.insert(28);
    b.insert(57);

    System.out.println("After fourth insert :" +b);
}
```

> Output

```
Before any insert :[-2147483648,-2147483648][2147483647,2147483647]
After first insert :[-2147483648,-2147483648][1,1][4,4][2147483647,2147483647]
After second insert :[-2147483648,-2147483648][1,1][4,4][18,18][23,23][2147483647,2147483647]
After third insert :[-2147483648,-2147483648][1,1][4,4][18,18][23,23][25,25][2147483647,2147483647]
After fourth insert :[-2147483648,-2147483648][1,1][4,4][18,18][23,23][25,25][28,28][57,57][2147483647,2147483647]
```

Regarding your second question - understanding `insert` method. The second and third `if` statements increasing max of the node or decreasing min of the next node if the difference in given number is by 1.

Last insert is creating a new node by same min and max if the given number does not fall in any of the given ranges.

I tried my best to explain, another approach is to run the `main` program in debug mode which will give you clear idea on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, kind of weird. Haven't seen something like this before but it's not too difficult to work out. One thing to remember here is that this is tracking *ranges* of numbers. In the example picture at the bottom, the ranges of numbers the data structure is representing are 1-4, 18-23, 25-25, and 28-57. When adding a number into this structure you will either create a new range, combine two ranges, expand the range's min or max by one, or find that the number is already represented in one of the ranges.

1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
if (p.min <= nbr && p.max >= nbr) {
    return false;
}
```

This means the number you have given the method is between the min and max in a node and the method will return false. Cool.  This is the *find that the number is already represented in one of the ranges* option.

2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
if (p.max + 1 == nbr && p.next.min - 1 == nbr) {
    p.max = p.next.max;
    p.next = p.next.next;
    break;
}
```

^ In this case, the number is one greater than the max of the current node and one less than the min of the next node. Imagine two nodes:

```
Node 1:  min -> 4, max -> 8
Node 2:  min -> 10, max -> 13
Input Number: 9
```

So, what we have here is the numbers 4 - 8 represented in node 1 and 10 - 13 represented in node two. When inserting the number nine we now have 4-8, 9-9, 10-13 represented. That doesn't make any sense to store it that way. Saying 4-13 is represented is the exact same thing as saying 4-8, 9-9, and 10-13 is represented. So, what this does is take the next node's max (in this case 10) and max it the current nodes max and then dump node 2. So we go from:

```
Node 1:  min -> 4, max -> 8, nextNode -> Node 2
Node 2:  min -> 10, max -> 13, nextNode -> Node 3
```

To

```
Node 1: min -> 4, max -> 13, nextNode -> Node 3
```

This is the *combine two ranges* option.

3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
else if (p.max + 1 == nbr) {
    p.max = nbr;
    break;
}
```

Because the number is just one more than the current nodes max, you just replace the current nodes max by one. So for one node with a range 1-3, you insert 4 and just change the 1-3 node to 1-4.

```
else if (p.next.min - 1 == nbr) {
    p.next.min = nbr;
    break;
}
```

Same as the last one expect you are "expanding" the min. So a node with a range 4-7, you insert 3, 4-7 becomes 3-7. Both of the above are the *expand the range* options.

4~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
else if (p.max < nbr && p.next.min > nbr) {
    Node n = new Node(nbr, nbr);
    n.next = p.next;
    p.next = n;
    break;
}
```

In this case, the number lies into between two ranges. Range 1: 4 - 8, Range 2: 17 - 24. You input 14 in this case and you cannot fit it into either of these ranges or expand the ranges to fit it. So, you create a new Range and put it between them. It becomes, Range 1: 4-8, Range 2: 14-14, Range 3: 17-24. This is the *create a new range* option.

5~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
p = p.next;
```

If you have gotten here, none of the above scenarios have applied. At this point you move on to the next node and check if any of the above conditions apply there.

I hope this helps, it took me a bit to figure this thing out but I'm pretty sure everything above is correct.